# Silverlight different behaviour when being run from website

Tags: c#, silverlight, storyboard

I am working on a simple Silverlight application. The point of application is to display data loaded from XML file. Data consists of **String "password"** and **Integer "passwordCount"**. Each loaded position is displayed as a coloured square and whenever user moves mouse over this square it is resized to "passwordCount/10" pixel width or height and the "password" string is displayed on it. Here is an example:

On Mouseover:
[image]

Everything works fine if I run it via VisualStudio Run button. The problem is that when I place the script on website, tiles resize in the wrong direction (they become smaller instead of bigger). The text is not displayed either. I don't have the faintest idea why. Silverlight on website opens in a separate window and it looks like that on mouseover:

[image]
<sub>(source: [screenshu.com](https://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/x9/qg/l9/q4jrro.jpg))</sub>

Here is the function I use to animate tiles:

```
    public void rectangle_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        sbMouseON = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation sizeAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        sizeAnimation.To = passwordCount/10; //passwordCount is always greater than 1000
        sizeAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(sizeAnimation, (Rectangle)sender);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(sizeAnimation, new PropertyPath(direction));
        sbMouseON.Children.Add(sizeAnimation); 

        Canvas.SetZIndex(rect, 2); //move rectangle up to make animation visible
        DrawTextBlock();
        sbMouseON.Begin();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mods: Can't Add Comment so posting as answer**

Here I am assuming that the "direction" you are passing in the TargetProperty is "(FrameworkElement.Width)" to increase the width of the rectangle.

If so only Logical Reason a Object can reduce in size is "sizeAnimation.To" property you are setting is setting the value which is smaller than the actual width of the object.

What is this DrawTextBlock() doing ? is there any code in there which can change the behavior of animation ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved itself. I've just copied all files onto server and it works great. Looks like it was some Windows problem. Thank you for your interest @Abhinav.